# Linux ethernet traffic capture

Tags: linux, capture, ethernet, traffic

What programs under Linux can capture ethernet traffic? And which ones from them are maintained and most comfortable?

Comment: There's tcpdump available, it captures traffic on specified network interface. As for other programs, someone with more experience will probably post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

[tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is awesome for capturing traffic coming into or out of your machine. [Ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/) is awesome if you want to MITM traffic. If you prefer a GUI then [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a good alternative.

Example usage:

```
tcpdump src 10.0.0.1 port 80

ettercap -T -Q -M arp:remote -i eth0 /10.0.0.1/ // -P remote_browser
```

Answer (score 3):

[wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Don't forget the command line version `tshark`.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is great. Runs on Linux and Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you want a console-based graphics dump of the ethernet traffic you can use `iptraf` as well.